# How to write a sumproduct with multiple conditions style to avoid adding extra column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Last time, I asked a question about how to do a sumproductIF for one condition and it works great.  However, if there are two (or more condition), I would like to know how to write a sumproduct  with multiple conditions style to avoid adding extra column.

[image]

The purpose of the calculation is to find the final total cost of T1 in USD with single step

Currently, the total cost of T1 in USD can be found by find the Price*QTY with currency conversion (step 1 in the picture), then find total of T1 by SUMIF(TYPE,"T1",Price*QTY)

Comment: If you're open to a different approach, I'd keep the table, with the intermediate column, and then use it as the source for a pivot table.  This will give you a lot of flexibility in your analysis.  I'd also be nervous about eliminating the middle column and relying on a "superformula," because errors will be harder to spot.

Comment: @DougGlancy - thanks.  I just would like to try a way, however, if it is not possible or too complex then I will go back to original one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use SUMIF instead of LOOKUP then you don't need to sort the currency table, i.e.

`=SUMPRODUCT((A10:A24="T1")+0,B10:B24,D10:D24,SUMIF(B$4:$B$6,C10:C24,$C$4:$C$6))`

Comment: + 1 Nice one as usual Barry :)

Answer (score 1):

If the fx rate table can be ordered (in alphabetic order) and include USD = 1, you could use this array-formula (you need to validate it by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`):

```
=SUM((A10:A24="T1")*(B10:B24)*(D10:D24)*(LOOKUP(C10:C24,$B$4:$B$6,$C$4:$C$6)))
```

This assumes that:

- the fx table is in B4:C6, with EURO, JPY and USD in that order
- the main data table is in A9:E24 (titles on line 9)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, data is not sorted and can be added or deleted.

Comment: @NCC it only needs the currency table to be sorted, not the main table. If you can't sort the currency table then the formula I propose will not work.

Comment: thank you for the answer.  I guess it is better to use "middle" column